# how to make views in odoo display no records until the user search?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to make my kanban view is default one but also I'm in need to make it not to display any record by default until the end-user search for the specific record he want to edit it, is there is any way to achieve that from action or any other way, by limit I can achieve only one record, and I'm tried to add auto_seaerh parameter = False in action but still display records by default

Comment: create a `TransientModel` and use onchange decorator.

Comment: then define the `ir.actions.act_window` module's attribute `view_type` only allow `form`. And `target` is `inline`.

Comment: i can't get what are you talking about